# Trying to create array of spinners

Tags: android, spinner

I create array of spinners but when i run in emulator the spinner like "hide" others spinner. how i can set the position of spinner so it could automatically form in a good order.
here my code

```
Spinner[] arrSpinner = new Spinner[10];
    ArrayAdapter arrAdapter[] = new ArrayAdapter[10];
    List[] listSoal = new ArrayList[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){  
        listSoal[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
        listSoal[i].add("Soal "+i);
    }
    List[] listJawaban = new ArrayList[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){  
        listJawaban[i] = new ArrayList<String>();                           
        listJawaban[i].add("Pilih Jawaban");
        listJawaban[i].add("Pilihan 2");
        listJawaban[i].add("Pilihan 3");
        listJawaban[i].add("Pilihan 4");

    }
    int soal = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setText("Soal "+soal);
        addContentView(tv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //addContentView(tv, null);
        arrSpinner[i] = new Spinner(this,0);
        arrAdapter[i] = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,listJawaban[i]);
        arrSpinner[i].setPrompt("Pilih Jawaban");
        addContentView(arrSpinner[i], new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        arrAdapter[i].setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        arrSpinner[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerAction());
        arrSpinner[i].setAdapter(arrAdapter[i]);
        soal++;
    }
```

this is the result

[image]

Comment: can u plz show layout

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
addContentView(tv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

You are putting them all in the same position.

If you are putting these in a FrameLayout you need to use something like `MarginLayoutParams` and give each view a top margin to space them out.

Or you can just fix it by putting them in a LinearLayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should have some LinearLayout or other layout as root layout to add your dynamic spinner as child for that view.

For that you have to do like , `View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.layoutID);` So now your all `spinner will be add child of`linearLayout

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
spinner .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
... 
...
//then you spinner adapter code 
linearlayout1.addView(spinner);
```

I hope this will help you to manage dynamic spinner in same way even if you don't have any `LinearLayout` then you can create that dynamically and use it.

```
LinearLayout linearlayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
linearlayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
linearlayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams );
```

Answer (score 0):

multiple spinner by using layout

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
         ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.get(i));
         dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         ll.addView(spinner, params);

}
alert.setView(ll);
```